# cannot import name ExtendedInterpolation

Tags: python, importerror

Interestingly, on my machine (OSX) importing the package hgvs runs smoothly, even though I'm working on python 2.7 (and ExtendedInterpolation is a python 3 function from configparser). As far as what I've gathered, it simply uses a backport of Python 3's configparser module, so it should work anyways if Python 3 is installed. 
However, the following error occurs when I try to import the module on a EC2 instace using iPython Notebook.

Any ideas of what may be causing the issue?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-832dbede7fbb> in <module>()
----> 1 import hgvs.location

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hgvs/hgvs/__init__.py in <module>()
     57 import warnings
     58 
---> 59 from .config import global_config    # flake8: noqa; importing symbol
     60 
     61 logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hgvs/hgvs/config.py in <module>()
     22 from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
     23 
---> 24 from configparser import ConfigParser, ExtendedInterpolation
     25 from copy import copy
     26 import logging

ImportError: cannot import name ExtendedInterpolation
```

Comment: Just downloaded the configparser backport 3.5.0 on my windows box with python 2.7 and it worked fine. Do you use the latest backport?

Comment: that's not using python3 on that machine, it's also using python 2.7. having python 3 installed doesn't automatically make it available for nearby python 2.7 configs as well; they're all independent.

Comment: It works as well on my machine. I'll try upgrading python on the server.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://bitbucket.org/ambv/configparser/issues/8/configparser-import-broken-on-py27) the problem is that:

> Unfortunately in 0.14.0 they broke the configparser import by introducing their own.

To resolve it, I downgraded the future library:

```
pip install future==0.13.1
```